# How to render a list of dataframes as tables to show as output in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working in a shiny app to compare multiple items according to an input defined by the user. The code works fine but I have an issue. I do not know what function I should apply in order to display the results of some computing as tables in the right side of the app. The code of the app is next:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

#Function

compute <- function(firstitem,seconditem)
{
  Sum <- firstitem+seconditem
  Difference <- firstitem+seconditem
  Product <- firstitem*seconditem
  Ratio <- firstitem/seconditem
  Res <- data.frame(C1=Sum,C2=Difference,C3=Product,C4=Ratio)
  return(Res)
}

#App

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Compare"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("numitems", label = "Number of items to compare?",
                   min = 1, max = 5, value = 1),
      uiOutput("period_cutpoints"),
      uiOutput("period_cutpoints2"),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("numitems"),
      textOutput("cutpoints")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$period_cutpoints<-renderUI({
    req(input$numitems)
    lapply(1:(input$numitems), function(i) {
      numericInput(inputId=paste0("firstitem",i), 
                   label=paste0("Enter the value of first item ", i, ":"),value = 0)
    })
  })
  
  output$period_cutpoints2<-renderUI({
    req(input$numitems)
    lapply(1:(input$numitems), function(i) {
      numericInput(inputId=paste0("seconditem",i), 
                   label=paste0("Enter the value of second item ", i, ":"),value = 0)
    })
  })
  
  seldates <- reactiveValues(x=NULL)
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    seldates$x <- list()
    lapply(1:(input$numitems), function(i) { 
      seldates$x[[i]] <- compute(firstitem = input[[paste0("firstitem", i)]],seconditem = input[[paste0("seconditem", i)]])
    })
  })
  
  output$cutpoints <- renderText({as.character(seldates$x)})
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It is working but my issue is that I do not know how to set the content of `seldates`, which are dataframes, as tables that should appear one after another. This task is done with `output$cutpoints` but I can not get them as Tables:

[image]

Does anybody know how can I fix this issue? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
#Function

compute <- function(firstitem,seconditem)
{
  Sum <- firstitem+seconditem
  Difference <- firstitem+seconditem
  Product <- firstitem*seconditem
  Ratio <- firstitem/seconditem
  Res <- data.frame(C1=Sum,C2=Difference,C3=Product,C4=Ratio)
  return(Res)
}

#App

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Compare"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("numitems", label = "Number of items to compare?",
                   min = 1, max = 5, value = 1),
      uiOutput("period_cutpoints"),
      uiOutput("period_cutpoints2"),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("numitems"),
      textOutput("cutpoints"),
      uiOutput("t1")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$period_cutpoints<-renderUI({
    req(input$numitems)
    lapply(1:(input$numitems), function(i) {
      numericInput(inputId=paste0("firstitem",i), 
                   label=paste0("Enter the value of first item ", i, ":"),value = i)
    })
  })
  
  output$period_cutpoints2<-renderUI({
    req(input$numitems)
    lapply(1:(input$numitems), function(i) {
      numericInput(inputId=paste0("seconditem",i), 
                   label=paste0("Enter the value of second item ", i, ":"),value = i+i)
    })
  })
  
  seldates <- reactiveValues(x=NULL)
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    seldates$x <- list()
    lapply(1:(input$numitems), function(i) { 
      seldates$x[[i]] <- compute(firstitem = input[[paste0("firstitem", i)]],seconditem = input[[paste0("seconditem", i)]])
    })
  })
  
  output$cutpoints <- renderText({as.character(seldates$x)})
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    
    lapply(1:(input$numitems), function(i) { 
      output[[paste0("table",i)]] <- renderDT(seldates$x[[i]])
    })
    
    output$t1 <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        lapply(1:(input$numitems), function(i) { 
          DTOutput(paste0("table",i))
        })
      )
    })
    
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Comment: Many thanks for you help. I have the app working now. I accepted the answer and if you have time, could you please check this new question? Many thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479307/how-to-add-warnings-to-ui-outputs-generated-dynamically-in-shiny